# How many subgroup has $\mathbb{Z_p}$ with $p$ prime

Tags: group-theory

My try is how $\mathbb{Z_p} $ is a group of order $p$ prime by theorem we know thata group of prime order has only two subgroups: itself and ${e}$

is this right?

And how can i draw de hasse diagram of all subgroups of $\mathbb{Z_p}$ I think its just $Z_p$ and $e$ united by a line

Comment: Yes, you're correct.

Answer (score 0):

Hint : How many elements of order $p$ are in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ ? And how many will create the same subgroup ?

Comment: Just the number 1 has order p

Comment: @AlbertoDuran Are you sure ? What about every non-zero class ?